# TypeScript: Error:(34, 50) TS17009: 'super' must be called before accessing 'this' (possible to disable error)

Tags: typescript

The following TypeScript:

```
constructor(options?:any) {
    this.m_options = options;
    this.m_blockType = 6022;
    _.extend(this.m_options, {blockType: this.m_blockType});
    super();
}
```

Produces the error:

> Error:(34, 50) TS17009: 'super' must be called before accessing 'this'
>   in the constructor of a derived class.

I want to call super after setting options. Is there a way to disable the TypeScript error?

Comment: Can you provide more context on why you want to do this?  It seems like you are fighting the language a bit.  You could always call super before and after.

Comment: well I can do a few workarounds to fix this, I was wondering just if there us a way ignore the error via tsconfig option, if not there are few things I can do... tx for the reply.

Comment: 'this' refers to the instance, but that instance has not yet been fully created. That happens after calling super. So it doesn't make sense to try to use 'this' before it is even defined!

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to disable the TypeScript error?

Nope. I requested something similar once : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4094 Please feel free to create a new issue with a clearer purpose of disabling errors for particular sections

Comment: will do! I think it would be great to be able to hide specific errors